# report does not generate in cucumber it just simply executes simple text editor

Tags: java, selenium, maven, cucumber, report

i used updated io.cucumber dependencies previously i used info.cukes in which my project executes perfectly after updating it into updated version in io.cucumber it doesn't allowed to generate bunch of report along with index.html instead of that it simply says simple text editor format

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.framework.org</groupId>
    <artifactId>CucumberFramework</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>CucumberFramework</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>7.2.3</version>
</dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>7.2.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
    <version>7.2.3</version>
</dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-jvm -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
    <version>7.2.3</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-picocontainer -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
    <version>7.2.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-jvm-deps -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.6</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-gherkin -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-gherkin</artifactId>
    <version>7.2.3</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-html -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-html</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.7</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-testng -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
    <version>7.2.3</version>
</dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <parallel>Classes</parallel>
                    <threadCount>2</threadCount>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Runner.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

i attached my pom.xml file and i tried change dependencies also but it didn't work and i this is my stepdefinition file

```
package stepDefinition;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import io.cucumber.java.After;
import io.cucumber.java.Before;
import io.cucumber.java.en.*;



public class StepFile {
    public static WebDriver driver;

@Before 
public void launchBrowser() {
    System.out.println("Launch the Browser");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
            "C:\\Users\\archukrish\\eclipse-workspace\\Automation Practice\\Driver\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
}

@After
public void quitBrowser() {
    System.out.println("Close Browser");
    driver.quit();
}

@Given("^user is on Home page$")
public void user_is_on_Home_page() {
    driver.get("https://www.demoblaze.com/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

}

@When("^user select the \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void user_select_the_items(String items) {
    WebElement Product= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h4[@class='card-title']//a[text()='"+items+"']"));
    Product.click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

 }

@Then("^user click on add cart$")
public void user_click_on_add_cart() throws InterruptedException {
    WebElement add=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Add to cart']"));
    add.click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
 }

@Then("^click ok on alert box$")
public void click_ok_on_alert_box() {
    Alert ac= driver.switchTo().alert();
    ac.accept();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    
  }

@Then("^user click on cart$")
public void user_click_on_cart() {
    WebElement cart =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Cart']"));
    cart.click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

}

@Then("^select the delete option$")
public void select_the_delete_option() throws InterruptedException {
    WebElement delete =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Delete']"));
    delete.click();
    
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.close();

}
}
```

this is my runner class

```
package runner;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "src\\test\\resource\\featureFile", glue= {"stepDefinition"}, dryRun=true,
                 monochrome= true, plugin= {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber", "json:target/cucumber.json"} )
public class Runner {

}
```

and this is my report [target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rD7nO.png)[json report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYm3m.png)

Comment: Try `html:target/cucumber/index.html`.

Comment: still the prblm is not solved